# nucleo-f401re button interrupt keep getting into the irq handler

Tags: stm32, nucleo

the nucleo board button is pulled up to high to gpioc13 so i made the interrupt on a falling edge , the code keeps getting into the irq handler without me pushing the button 
my main.c

```
#include "Board_LED.h"
#include "stm32f401xe.h"

void PIN_CONFG();
void PIN_EN();
void clear();

int main(void) {
  LED_Initialize();
  PIN_CONFG(13);
  PIN_EN(13);

  LED_On(0);
  while(1){
  }

  return 0;
}

void delay(void) {
  int i; 
  for(i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
  } 
}

void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void) {
  clear(13);
  LED_On(0);
  delay();
  LED_Off(0);
  delay();
}
```

my interrupt functions.c

```
#include "stm32f401xe.h"

void PIN_CONFG(uint16_t pin) {
  EXTI->FTSR |= (1 << pin); 
}

void PIN_EN(uint16_t pin) {
  EXTI->IMR |= (1<<pin);    
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(40);
}

void clear(uint16_t pin) {
  if(EXTI->PR & (1<<pin)) {
    EXTI->PR |= (1<<pin);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Did you try to stick to some tutorial like e.g. https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/08/stm32f4-external-interrupts-tutorial/?

Answer (score 2):

The source pin for `EXTI13` must be selected. It can be any of `PA13`, `PB13`, `PC13` etc, and the `SYSCFG->EXTICR` registers tell the system which one to use.

```
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SYSCFGEN;
RCC->APB2ENR; // see "Delay after an RCC peripheral clock enabling" in the errata sheet
SYSCFG->EXTICR[3] |= SYSCFG_EXTICR4_EXTI13_PC; // EXTICR4 in the Reference Manual correspond to EXTICR[3]!
```

Without setting it defaults to `PA13` (value 0), which is used as the `SWDIO` line from the onboard debugger. *Any* activity by the debugger triggers the interrupt.

By the way, don't forget to enable `GPIOC` in the clock controller. Same errata as above applies, you might want to interleave it with the code above to have the necessary delays without extra code.

```
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SYSCFGEN;
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN;
SYSCFG->EXTICR[3] |= SYSCFG_EXTICR4_EXTI13_PC;
```